# Why there is not any Bolt for storing crawl results in Stormcrawler when we are using RDBMS?

Tags: stormcrawler

I want to use Stormcrawler with an RDBMS engines like Oracle, MySQL, or Postgres. But in the storm-crawler-sql module, we only have a SqlSpout and a StatusUpdaterBolt. We did not find any class for indexing crawl results to the SQL database. Is there any technical reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with the [IndexerBolt](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/sql/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/sql/IndexerBolt.java)?

Comment: I am sorry. It seems I asked a wrong question. My question about the table which should store the content of web pages. In the tableCreation.script there is not any table for saving crawl results.